# Почему не выводится переменная в шаблон HTML?

Tags: angularjs

Ловлю переменную от роутинга Angular JS:

```
if ($routeParams.page) {
    $scope.selectedTab = $routeParams.page;
}
```

Далее вывожу в темплайте:

```
<div ng-controller="EditProfileController">{{selectedTab}}</div>
```

Но получаю пустой текст. Ошибок нет. Контроллеры расставлены правильно. В `$scope.selectedTab` значение присутствует в контроллере

Comment: Если блок if выполняется, то значит причина только одна - действительно нет того, что можно отобразить. Ответьте мне на свой же вопрос - почему в коде var a = b; а не равняется 5? Причин может быть просто дофигищи и Вы предлагаете Вам все сидеть и перечислять? Выкладывайте рулон кода и может кому-то не будет лень разбираться в нем и он Вам поможет.

Comment: Проблема в том - что контроллер быстрее отрабатывает чем срабатывает $route

Answer (score 1):

Если вы добавляете в шаблон

```
<div ng-controller="EditProfileController">{{selectedTab}}</div>
```

то в какой контроллер вы передаете `$scope.selectedTab` ?

Структура контроллеров должна быть примерно такой

```
+ Main Controller
+-- ProfileController
+---- EditProfileController
```

иначе, в шаблоне не может быть `ng-controller="EditProfileController"`, если только вы не показываете текущий контроллер в самом себе.

Чтобы корректно проверять `if ($routeParams.page)` в роутере можно добавить знак `?` для указания того, что параметр может отсутствовать

```
.when('/tab/:page?', {
    templateUrl: 'ProfileController.html',
    controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
  })
```

[Пример](http://embed.plnkr.co/loazDBLnannqTZaP0N5X/preview)